# Server side validation in SharePoint Framework (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am working on a SharePoint Framework based project in SharePoint Online and using React JS as front-end library. I am also using Redux for state management and React Hooks. I want to know how can I implement server-side validation in SharePoint Framework (with react JS), although I have already implemented client-side validations on the forms/components and on all the mandatory fields.

However, in the security testing of the application, it has been reported as an issue that there should be strict server-side validation in the fields - For Eg. - file types validation, file extension. Additionally, the application should implement strict server-side validation against all the mandatory fields in all the application forms / registration pages of the application.

Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Your early response would be highly appreciable, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint Framework does not support server-side validation directly. SPFx is purely clident-side. That being said, we can always make business critical SPFx apps more secure by offloading the logic away from SPFx.

**Options**

I think it's an overkill for the 99% of cases, but these are the options for including the server-side validation:

1. [Recommended] [Create an Azure function and call it from your SPFx solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi). Azure function will contain the validation code.
2. Create a provider-hosted SharePoint app instead of SPFx.